# Notation for vector time derivatives

Tags: vectors, soft-question, conventions, notation

So I am self-studying mechanics using Marion and, as many books, it uses the notation of the dot over the function to express a time derivative, as in
$$x = x(t)$$
$$\dot{x}= \frac{dx}{dt}(t) $$

The book also uses the bold notation for vectors, like for example the position vector is:
$$\textbf{r} = \textbf{r}(t)$$

Putting these together, we get that using this notation the velocity vector is:

$$ \textbf{v} (t) = \dot{\textbf{r}} (t)$$

My question is: when it comes to handwriting, which is the most common/ standard notation? Is it something like: $\dot{\vec{r}}$? Or do you stop specifying it as a vector with the arrow on top?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Consistent notation is needed for clear communication, but there is no one "correct" notation for anything.

If you can remember what things mean in your own work, you can do whatever you want.  If you are writing something that others must read too, like a graded homework assignment, it is important to define any notation.  That being said if you clearly define your notation, you can do whatever seems best to you.